# scanf reads the wrong char

Tags: c, scanf

I need to write a program in C that let's the user choose to draw a rectangle square or print the board he made but everytime after the first input of a shape the program acts as if he entered an invalid character.

```
printf("please make you decision R-rectangle, S-square, E-end\n");
scanf("%c", &decision);
do
{
    if (decision == 'R') {
        printf("you chose rectangle! please enter the X start position, Y start position, hieght and width\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &rectMat[0][rectCounter], &rectMat[1][rectCounter], &rectMat[2][rectCounter], &rectMat[3][rectCounter]);
        if (rectCounter + 1 < MAX_RECT)
        {
            if (checkRECT(rectMat[0][rectCounter], rectMat[1][rectCounter], rectMat[2][rectCounter], rectMat[3][rectCounter], areaMat) == 1)
            {
                drawRECT(rectMat[0][rectCounter], rectMat[1][rectCounter], rectMat[2][rectCounter], rectMat[3][rectCounter], areaMat);
                rectCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("we couldn't fit you rectangle\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("you have too many rectangles\n");
        }
    }

    if (decision == 'S')
    {
        printf("you chose square! please enter the X start position, Y start position and size of the side\n");
        scanf("%d  %d  %d", &sqrMat[0][rectCounter], &sqrMat[1][rectCounter], &sqrMat[2][rectCounter]);
        if (sqrCounter<MAX_SQR)
        {
            if (checkSQR(sqrMat[0][rectCounter], sqrMat[1][rectCounter], sqrMat[2][rectCounter],areaMat)==1)
            {
                drawSQR(sqrMat[0][rectCounter], sqrMat[1][rectCounter], sqrMat[2][rectCounter], areaMat);
                sqrCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("we couldn't fit your square\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("you have too many sqaures\n");
        }
    }
    if (decision == 'P')
    {
        printArea(areaMat);
    }
    if (decision != 'E'&& decision != 'P'&& decision != 'S'&& decision != 'R')
    {
        printf("invalid entry\n");
    }
    printf("please make you decision R-rectangle, S-square, E-end\n");
    scanf("%c", &decision);
} while (decision != 'E');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of some other `scanf` questions where it turned out OP didn't get rid of newline? Use `scanf(" %c", &decision);` (note the space) to get rid of the newline.

Comment: maybe you should check for 'r', 'p' and 's' instead of capitals

Comment: Look at that great honking blob of code, and it's *still* not compilable...

Comment: Also, reading user input with `scanf()` without even bothering to check the return code. Seriously. Your user will *always* do *correct* inputs only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read characters using the `"%c"` format, it will read the next character in the input buffer, it will not skip any white-space. And when using [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read anything, the newline you enter to send the input to the program will also be sent, and added as a white-space character after the end of your input. Most formats do skip leading white-space (like for example the `"%d"` format), but the `"%c"` and `"%["` formats do not.

When reading character it's almost always advisable to skip leading white-space, which is done by adding a space before the format, like e.g.

```
scanf(" %c", &decision);
//     ^
//     |
// Note space here
```

---

Also note that there is a difference between upper- and lower-case letters. `'R' != 'r'`. Either check for both upper- and lower-case letters, or use [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) (or [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower)) to convert.

Answer (score 1):

you better off using `getc()` instad of `scanf()` since you're expecting a single char anyway